# How do I write a list and two np. arrays to a .csv file using sci-kit-learn and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to write out a list as header and two np.arrays out to a .csv so I can read them back in again. I am new to sci-kit-learn and numpy. I read in the original .csv but greatly modified data and dimensions. Now I wat to write it out, but am at a loss.

I have feature_names = [' age', 'sex', 'height', 'weight', 'shape'] for row headers of type list.

I have a np.array X = [ 31.19418104   0.           1.           0.           0.        ]
a 984 x 5 array of float

I have a np.array y = 1.0, it is a 984 x 1 array of float

I to write the feature_names, X and y to a .csv file to save and read in again later.

I would like the CSV format to be:
feature_names
X[0] y[0]
.....
X[984] y[984]

Row 0"age","sex","height","weight","shape"

Row 1 "31.19418104","0."," 1.","0.", "0.", "1.0"

Row  n-1 .......

I need to maintain this format for the work I am doing.

I was hoping to do something like:

```
import csv

f = open("output.csv)
r = writer()
len = colLen(X)
r.writerrow(feature_name)
for x to len-1
    r.writerrow(X,y)
f.close()
```

I gave up after trying to find docs (2 days) and would appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Are you gonna read them back again with python? If so you could just save the array in binary. np.save

Comment: I will be using python but they must be human readable and available to other programming languages and tools so yup ... that's where I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to concatenate your arrays and [`savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) to save to csv (links to docs included)

Demo. Using StringIO is for demonstration purposes, you can provide your file path instead:

Set up data and stack:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np
# for repeatability
np.random.seed(11)
X = np.random.rand(984,5)
y = np.random.rand(984,1)
Xy = np.hstack([X,y])
```

Now we have

```
>>> X[:4]
array([[ 0.18026969,  0.01947524,  0.46321853,  0.72493393,  0.4202036 ],
       [ 0.4854271 ,  0.01278081,  0.48737161,  0.94180665,  0.85079509],
       [ 0.72996447,  0.10873607,  0.89390417,  0.85715425,  0.16508662],
       [ 0.63233401,  0.02048361,  0.11673727,  0.31636731,  0.15791231]])
>>> y[:4]
array([[ 0.2880356 ],
       [ 0.83924851],
       [ 0.92760524],
       [ 0.29316801]])
>>> Xy
array([[ 0.18026969,  0.01947524,  0.46321853,  0.72493393,  0.4202036 ,
         0.2880356 ],
       [ 0.4854271 ,  0.01278081,  0.48737161,  0.94180665,  0.85079509,
         0.83924851],
       [ 0.72996447,  0.10873607,  0.89390417,  0.85715425,  0.16508662,
         0.92760524],
       ...,
       [ 0.0589937 ,  0.09835012,  0.24966667,  0.33485216,  0.48755067,
         0.32618452],
       [ 0.67798696,  0.0563275 ,  0.83806763,  0.14160098,  0.53686285,
         0.49052511],
       [ 0.36844028,  0.82034601,  0.82753566,  0.96210629,  0.63720074,
         0.12148659]])
```

Save to buffer (or to a file):

```
>>> feature_names = [' age', 'sex', 'height', 'weight', 'shape']
>>> header = ', '.join(feature_names)
>>> buf = StringIO()
>>> np.savetxt(buf, Xy, fmt="%f", delimiter=', ', header=header)
>>> print '\n'.join(buf.getvalue().splitlines()[:4])
#  age, sex, height, weight, shape
0.180270, 0.019475, 0.463219, 0.724934, 0.420204, 0.288036
0.485427, 0.012781, 0.487372, 0.941807, 0.850795, 0.839249
0.729964, 0.108736, 0.893904, 0.857154, 0.165087, 0.927605
```

Note, that you probably don't need to add quotes `"` for your values, as if added, a csv reader will treat them as strings, not floats

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    out_csv = csv.writer(f)
    headers = [' age', 'sex', 'height', 'weight', 'shape']
    out_csv.writerow(headers)
    myArray = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,11]])
    for row in myArray:
        out = row.tolist() + [1] #if they're all just ones. 
        out_csv.writerow(out)
```

Output:
 age,sex,height,weight,shape
1,2,3,4,5,1
6,7,8,9,11,1

Comment: This looks really great, but I got this errot: Xy = np.hstack([X_train,y_train])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 275, in hstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Comment: commented on wrong answer. but anyway, can you show the X_train.shape and y_train.shape?

Comment: I check the dimensons for X and y respectivly and got:

Comment: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(984, 5)
(984,)

Comment: y_train.resize(y_train.shape[0],1) try this before the hstack function

Comment: As to M4rtini, they are not all ones, some are zeros.

Comment: M4rtini U nailed it! WTH (what the heck). does y_train.resize(y_train.shape[0],1) mean! Can I impose on you for references to dealing with arrays and IO in numpy? I know OCTAVE and R and I got no choice ... Fastest turnaround on stack ever. You guys Rock!!!!!!

Comment: @ChrisRigano you can use `np.hstack([X_train,y_train[..., None]])` if your y_train lacks one dimension. `y_train[..., None]` equals `y_train.resize(y_train.shape[0],1)` equals `y_train.resize(-1,1)` adds a dimension to y, making it 2d with shape (984, 1) instead of 1-dimensional (984,).

Comment: It simply resizes the (984,) array into a (984,1). http://scipy-lectures.github.io/ this is a good reference for more info

Comment: SPOKE too soon got an extra element in X

Comment: '31.194181' ' 1.000000' ' 0.000000' ' 0.000000' ' 1.000000' ' 0.000000']  0.000

Comment: how does the first row of x, y and xy look? Edit it into the question so it's easier to read.

Comment: I blew it you guys were right all is good! One last question: when I do:feature_names = ['age', 'sex', 'first_class', 'second_class', 'third_class'], then  header = ', '.join(feature_names) then np.savetxt('titanic.csv', Xy, fmt="%f", delimiter=', ', header=header), I get a "#" in the header in the file : #age  sex first_class second_class .... 1) is there a way to get rid of this? 2) any book (kindle) online etc that can help me with numpy arrays and I/O ... U save my B__T! thanks M4rini ( E2 Alco!)

Comment: http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/index.html http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm no needs for books, you can find all the info for free on the net.

Comment: No idea about the # tho, double check that it's not in the original feature_names list.